# Why do Ω- hyperons spin as they do?

Tags: quantum-spin

A ∑-hyperon has a spin of ½ and so does the ᴧ-hyperon. However, the Ω- hyperon has a spin of 3/2. My question is ‘(i) What is the reason behind this? (ii) Is it possible to discover more hyperons with spins of (2n+1)/2?’  Please, give the reason for your answer to (ii).

Comment: Well, the (hypothetical, but nobody doubts them it's just that production cross-section are dizzyingly low) $\Omega_{ccc}^{++}$  and $\Omega_{bbb}^{--}$ also spin 3/2 mesons because they have very parallel structure to the $\Omega^{--}$ (which you could call a $\Omega_{sss}^{--}$ if you wanted to maintain a completely consistent notation). So perhaps you should be asking yourself what is the difference between these mesons and the other hyperons you mention.